# Rails: param is missing or the value is empty: stock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cloud9-ide, cloud9

I keep getting an error when i try to create a new item for a database that displays ActionController::ParameterMissing in StocksController#create
param is missing or the value is empty: stock.

It says the source is at

```
private 
 def stock_params
    params.require(:stock).permit(:product_name, :brand_name, :item_id, :upc_code, :color, :department, :size, :condition, :fabric_type, :shipping_weight, :sku, :asin, :quantity, :cost_price, :sell_price, :key_product_features,  :product_description, :search_terms, :status, :listing_in_usa, :listing_in_canada, :listing_in_mexico)   
end
```

Under my stockscontroller file on the terminal it says:

```
Started POST "/stocks" for 107.15.253.59 at 2017-05-22 16:38:14 +0000
Cannot render console from 107.15.253.59! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by StocksController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"poJrp+PWBi7bxgeauJ37VNh/Shyk0q6iCNA+5Y4UBIZ/rf5dXYVBOgtPpVPUbfzjLsn9Kcz/Fn6kHKXHG0dUuQ==", "stocks"=>{"product_name"=>"", "brand_name"=>"", "item_id"=>"", "upc_code"=>"", "color"=>"", "department"=>"", "size"=>"", "condition"=>"", "fabric_type"=>"", "shipping_weight"=>"", "sku"=>"", "asin"=>"", "quantity"=>"", "cost_price"=>"", "sell_price"=>"", "key_product_feature"=>"", "product_description"=>"", "search_terms"=>"", "status"=>"", "listing_in_usa"=>"", "listing_in_canada"=>"", "listing_in_mexico"=>""}, "commit"=>"Save Stocks"}
Completed 400 Bad Request in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: stock):

app/controllers/stocks_controller.rb:48:in `stock_params'
app/controllers/stocks_controller.rb:15:in `create'
```

I basically repeated a code that is similar to this that works that i already created, but i can't find why this is wrong. I have 2 types of databases, Vendors and Stocks, but the Stocks database isn't working.

This is the code for stockscontroller/concerns/controllers/apps

```
class StocksController < ApplicationController
def show
    @stock = Stock.find(params[:id])
end

def index
    @stocks = Stock.all
end

def new
    @stock = Stock.new
end

def create
    @stock = Stock.new(stock_params)


    if @stock.save
        redirect_to @stock
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def edit
    @stock = Stock.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @stock = Stock.find(params[:id])
    if @stock.update(stock_params)
        redirect_to @stock
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    @stock = Stock.find(params[:id])
    @stock.destroy

    redirect_to stock_path
end
end

private 
 def stock_params
    params.require(:stock).permit(:product_name, :brand_name, :item_id, :upc_code, :color, :department, :size, :condition, :fabric_type, :shipping_weight, :sku, :asin, :quantity, :cost_price, :sell_price, :key_product_features,  :product_description, :search_terms, :status, :listing_in_usa, :listing_in_canada, :listing_in_mexico)   
end
```

code for new/stocks/views/apps

```
<body>
    <div class = "head5">
        <h1>New Inventory</h1>

        <div class = "header5">
            <h3>  Apparel Inventory</h3>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
<%= form_for :stocks, url: stocks_path do |f| %>

<p>
    <%= f.label :product_name %><br>
   <%= f.text_field :product_name %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.label :brand_name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :brand_name %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.label :item_id %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :item_id %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.label :upc_code %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :upc_code %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.label :color %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :color %>
</p>


<p>
    <%= f.label :department %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :department %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.label :size %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :size %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.label :condition %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :condition %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.label :fabric_type %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :fabric_type %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.label :shipping_weight %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :shipping_weight %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.label :sku %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :sku %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.label :asin %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :asin %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.label :quantity %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :quantity %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.label :cost_price %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :cost_price %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.label :sell_price %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :sell_price %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.label :key_product_feature %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :key_product_feature %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.label :product_description %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :product_description %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.label :search_terms %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :search_terms %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.label :status %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :status %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.label :listing_in_usa %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :listing_in_usa %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.label :listing_in_canada %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :listing_in_canada %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.label :listing_in_mexico %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :listing_in_mexico %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.submit %>
</p>

<% end %>
<%= link_to 'Back', stocks_path %>
```

Code for the model

```
class Stock < ApplicationRecord
end
```

my routes/locals/config/app file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'

  resources :vendors
  resources :stocks


  root 'welcome#index'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

my schema/migrate/db/config/apps

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170522154349) do
  create_table "stocks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "product_name"
    t.string "brand_name"
    t.integer "item_id"
    t.integer "upc_code"
    t.string "color"
    t.string "size"
    t.string "department"
    t.string "condition"
    t.string "fabric_type"
    t.string "shipping_weight"
    t.string "sku"
    t.string "asin"
    t.integer "quantity"
    t.string "cost_price"
    t.string "sell_price"
    t.string "key_product_feature"
    t.text "product_description"
    t.text "search_terms"
    t.string "status"
    t.string "listing_in_usa"
    t.string "listing_in_canada"
    t.string "listing_in_mexico"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "vendors", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "company"
    t.string "contact_name"
    t.string "phone"
    t.string "email"
    t.string "moq"
    t.string "cost_per_item"
    t.string "payment_method"
    t.string "terms"
    t.string "turnover"
    t.string "returns"
    t.text "notes"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

The new error says:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in StocksController#show
Couldn't find Stock with 'id'=5
```

At the source on `app/controllers/stocks_controller.rb`:

```
class StocksController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @stock = Stock.find(params[:id])
    end

    def index
```

With the terminal saying:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Stock with 'id'=5):
app/controllers/stocks_controller.rb:3:in `show'
```

Comment: You're params are nested under the "stocks" key (plural), but you're controller is expecting "stock" (singular). Try changing form_for => :stock

Comment: Ok, thanks, but new problem. When I try to delete a record, I get another error. Gonna edit my question..

Comment: I have a new problem, editing my question for you guys to see

Comment: What were you doing when it could not find the record? Were you running a test? I don't see any tests in the question anymore.

I assume that there is no record with ID=5, as indicated in the error message, but I can't tell for sure if it's an error in the spec or somewhere else.

Comment: This seems to be new question. If the solutions below answered your first question, you should mart one as answered. You can create a new question for your second separate issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning a `:stock` key in your params.

Change

```
<%= form_for :stocks, url: stocks_path do |f| %>
```

Into

```
<%= form_for :stock, url: stocks_path do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a plural vs. sigular issue.

Your code is requiring a `stock` param, but it's getting `stocks`.

Try changing this line:
`<%= form_for :stocks, url: stocks_path do |f| %>`

to

`<%= form_for :stock, url: stocks_path do |f| %>`